# Can I draw with respect to the previous point rather than the current point in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I think I have seen some command like this before. Using `+` and `++` we can define coordinates relative to previous points on the path. I'm wondering whether `--` also has alternative versions that allow me to draw a line starting from a previous point rather than the current one. For example, consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0.5,0) -- +(0,1) --++ (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

What is the simplest way in which I could modify the MWE to get

[image]

instead?

Ideally, I would like to do it with a single `\draw` command and without doing stuff such as `\draw (0,0) -- (0.5,0) -- +(0.5,0) (0.5,0) -- (0.5,1);`, where the problem is solved by repeating one of the points. I would like to write each of the four points only once.

The reason is I'm working on an illustration which uses some random points, and I might not be able to get their coordinates again without considerably changing the implementation. Hence, in my goal each of the four points is sorted at random, and I will not be able to write them twice.

Comment: just use `coordinate` command?

Comment: No, you need to repeat this coordinate (some how).

Comment: (0,0) -- (1,0) (0.5,0)  -- ++(0,1) does all four points once each  ;=)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `coordinate` may be used:

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0.5,0) coordinate (tmp) -- +(0,1) (tmp) --++ (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `+` does not update the current point, but it updates the starting point of the path.

A possible solution, in the case of your MWE, could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0.5,0) -- +(0,1) |-++ (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,0) (0.5,0) -- +(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given the coordinate is "random" I think it would be rather unlikely for `|-` to work as expected...

Comment: @user202729 Using only 4 points there is no other solution, unless using `coordinate` as you suggested.